# Using variable in regex expression - escape characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a paragraph of text and a list of substrings from that text which I want to replace with a different substring.

```
newstring = "foo"
re_word = r'{0}'.format(word)
text = re.sub(re_word, newstring, text)
```

I'm doing this with a number of different 'paragraphs' of text. For some paragraphs it works fine, but for others I get the following error from the final line:

```
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 10
```

I suspect that the string I'm looking for contains a character that confuses Regex, ie. I need to escape it. How might I get around that?

Comment: Why use a regex here? Use `text = text.replace(word, newstring)`

Comment: I was doing that originally, but I want to use re.IGNORECASE.

Comment: Ok, good, so use `re.escape`. See the linked thread.

Comment: That's solved it. Thanks!